# Run Pod with unique POD name

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have a script which execute on container and i use following command to create my container and exit once execution complete, this is working as per our requirement.

```
kubectl run -i tmp-pod --rm -n=mynamespace --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides="$(cat POD.json)"
```

it creates the pod and execute my script and terminate the pod itself once completed.

But my above `kubectl` command runs by many sources  so if two source run same time then i get error `Error from server (AlreadyExists): pods "POD_NAME" already exists`

Is there anyway i can make my pod name unique so parallels  run does not conflict with other pod?

here is my POD.json

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "POD_NAME",
         
    },
    "spec": {
        "restartPolicy": "Never",
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "POD_NAME",
                "image": "my_IMAGE:2",
                "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                "command": [
                    "python",
                    "/myscript.py",
                    "INPUT_1",
                    "INPUT_2"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In the POD.json, will the metadata.name be unique? Or if not, what in this JSON will be unique?

Comment: @DennisvandeHoef every time pod creates with name ```POD_NAME```. I want something appended to my pod name to make it unique like  ```POD_NAME-<UNIQUE_CODE>```.  my pod just execute the script and exit so no unique anything in pod.

Comment: is in it easier to create a single replica deployment , so that pod that would get created will have random suffix.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, as everything is the same, I suggest you run your pod something like this. As far as I know, k8s does not give you a build in solution for this.

```sh
kubectl run -i tmp-pod$((1 + $RANDOM % 1000000)) --rm -n=mynamespace --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides="$(cat POD.json)"
```

For documentation purpose, in case the POD.json has changing values: Using JQ, you can read the changing values in the POD.json like this

```sh
kubectl run -i tmp-pod$(cat POD.json | jq -r '.metadata.name') --rm -n=mynamespace --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides="$(cat POD.json)"
```

In case the value you are reading is not valid as pod name, you could also simply generate a md5sum based on the POD.json and use a part of that like this. Using cut, to shorten it.

```sh
kubectl run -i tmp-pod$(md5sum POD.json | cut -c1-10) --rm -n=mynamespace --image=placeholder --restart=Never --overrides="$(cat POD.json)"
```